# Save RTSP stream to file

Tags: gstreamer

I cant save audio from stream I get only video in file. I suspect that I do not need two `filesink` in pipeline or there is some problem two different mux.

I tried to use `autoadiosink` and `autovideosink` and they works successfully.

`autoadiosink` and `autovideosink` pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov latency=0 droponlatency=1 name=rtp_source ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink rtp_source. ! queue ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink`

Save to file `filesink` pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov latency=0 droponlatency=1 name=rtp_source ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! vp8enc ! webmmux ! filesink location=BigBuckBunny_115k.webm rtp_source. ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio" ! queue ! decodebin ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=BigBuckBunny_115k.webm`

I want to get also audio in resulting file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just reuse the existing mux - so that the vorbis is put into the webmmux too:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov \
latency=0 droponlatency=1 name=rtp_source ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! \
vp8enc ! webmmux name=mux ! filesink location=BigBuckBunny_115k.webm rtp_source. ! \
application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio" ! queue ! decodebin ! vorbisenc ! mux.
```